# Multiprocessing: running a process several times while making its memory persist

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, subclassing

I'm facing an issue with Python's multiprocessing library that I can't find solved anywhere. I have a Python program that features a heavy task that I want to distribute across several cores, which all output to the same shared memory area, so that I can aggregate results at the end. The issue is that, I have to execute this task several times in a row, with each execution depending on the output of the previous one. To make it clearer, here is a minimal reproduction of what I would like to achieve.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from logzero import logger
import random


class Processor(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue, idx, rand_int):
        super(Processor, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.idx = idx
        self.rand_int = rand_int # could be any argument to persist across iterations

    def run(self):
        logger.debug(f"Process {self.idx}")
        for _ in range(500_000_000): # just a random task to use the CPU
            pass
        new_rand_int = random.randint(0, 1000)
        logger.debug(
            f"Process {self.idx}, previous rand_int: {self.rand_int}, "
            f"new rand_int: {new_rand_int}"
        )
        self.rand_int = new_rand_int # make sure that the old value of the parameter
                                     # remains accessible across iterations


if __name__ == "__main__":

    processes = []
    q = Queue()
    for i in range(2):
        p = Processor(queue=q, idx=i, rand_int=i)
        processes.append(p)

    for i in range(5):
        if i == 0:
            for process in processes:
                process.start()
        else:
            for process in processes:
                process.run()

        for process in processes: # wait until all processes finished the task before
                                  # launching another iteration
            process.join()
```

This code does not raise any exception but from the second iteration, the task is not distributed anymore across CPUs of my machine. Each process works one at a time on the same core, as shown by the following logs:

```
[D 220318 17:20:39 test_multiprocessing:18] Process 0
[D 220318 17:20:39 test_multiprocessing:18] Process 1
[D 220318 17:20:49 test_multiprocessing:22] Process 1, previous rand_int: 1, new rand_int: 808
[D 220318 17:20:49 test_multiprocessing:22] Process 0, previous rand_int: 0, new rand_int: 262
[D 220318 17:20:49 test_multiprocessing:18] Process 0
[D 220318 17:20:57 test_multiprocessing:22] Process 0, previous rand_int: 0, new rand_int: 938
[D 220318 17:20:57 test_multiprocessing:18] Process 1
[D 220318 17:21:06 test_multiprocessing:22] Process 1, previous rand_int: 1, new rand_int: 542
```

I can't re-create all the processes at each iteration as in reality, my class loads a heavy amount of memory in a complex object structure (up to several gigabytes), which current state evolves between iterations.

My question is three-fold:

1. Is there a pythonic solution to this issue using the multiprocessing library or something else ?
2. If this not possible in Python, should I change my stack to a lower-level language (like C++ for instance), which would enable such thing (although I'm not even sure about it)
3. Is it more appropriate to use a framework dedicated to distributed computing (like Spark for instance), even though the data structure of the program is very much object oriented and I'm not sure if it would fit Spark.

**Edit: thanks to @jsbueno for his answer.**

My main issue is to have processes waiting for each other at the end of each iteration so that I can perform aggregation on their outputs which influences the next iteration. The example below is a better representation of the matter.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, shared_memory
from logzero import logger
import random
import numpy as np

D_TYPE = np.float64
D_SHAPE = (2,)
D_SIZE = np.dtype(D_TYPE).itemsize * np.prod(D_SHAPE)


class Processor(Process):
    def __init__(self, cq, queue, idx, shm):
        super(Processor, self).__init__()
        self.cq = cq
        self.queue = queue
        self.idx = idx
        self.shm = shm
        self.data = np.ndarray(shape=D_SHAPE, dtype=D_TYPE, buffer=shm.buf)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            task = self.cq.get()
            if task == "rehash":
                self.rehash()
            elif task == "finish":
                break  # this ends the "run" method, exiting the subprocess

    def rehash(self):
        for _ in range(500_000_000):
            pass
        rand = random.randint(0, 1000)
        self.data[self.idx] += rand
        logger.debug(f"Process {self.idx}, rand: {rand}, self.data: {self.data}")


def command():
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=D_SIZE)
    data = np.ndarray(shape=D_SHAPE, dtype=D_TYPE, buffer=shm.buf)
    data[:] = 0

    processes = []
    q = Queue()
    for i in range(2):
        cq = Queue(5)
        p = Processor(cq=cq, queue=q, idx=i, shm=shm)
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for i in range(5):
        for process in processes:
            process.cq.put("rehash")

        # Here I would need for processes to join before aggregating the
        # shared memory array in the parent
        logger.debug(f"In main process: data: {data}, sum: {np.sum(data)}")
        if np.sum(data) > 1000:
            data[:] = 0
            logger.debug(f"Reinitializing data to: {data}")

    # this just needs to run when all tasks are done
    for process in processes:
        process.cq.put("finish")
        process.join()

    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    command()
```

Comment: You may be able to do it using [`multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#module-multiprocessing.shared_memory).

Comment: @martineau Indeed, I thought about having a shared memory array in which each process flags that it finished a task, which would trigger the main process to perform its aggregations and so on but that didn't seem to me as a very Pythonic way to do it. Hopefully, there is a cleaner solution somewhere, otherwise I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spawning new processes, each running one simple task, you can rewrite your worker process so that they can communicate better with a master process.

A "command" function in loop, which would pick commands sent down by the master process, and execute subtasks as required - so loading the datasets would be one of the first sets, and then the following tasks would be passed on by wire. You can use a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance to pass commands to each worker.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from logzero import logger
import random


class Processor(Process):
    def __init__(self, cq, queue, idx, rand_int):
        super(Processor, self).__init__()
        self.cq = cq
        self.queue = queue
        self.idx = idx
        self.rand_int = rand_int # could be any argument to persist across iterations

    def run(self):
        while True:
            task = self.cq.get()
            if task == "initalize":
                self.initialize()
            elif task == "rehash":
                self.rehash()
            elif task == "finish":
                break # this ends the "run" method, exiting the subprocess

    def initialize(self):

        logger.debug(f"Process {self.idx}")
        for _ in range(500_000_000): # just a random task to use the CPU
            pass
    def rehash(self):
        new_rand_int = random.randint(0, 1000)
        logger.debug(
            f"Process {self.idx}, previous rand_int: {self.rand_int}, new rand_int: {new_rand_int}"
        )
        self.rand_int = new_rand_int # make sure that the old value of the parameter remains accessible across iterations


def command():

    processes = []
    q = Queue()
    for i in range(2):
        cq = Queue(5)
        p = Processor(cq=cq, queue=q, idx=i, rand_int=i)
        processes.append()
        p.start()

    for i in range(5):
        if i == 0:

            for process in processes:
                process.cq.put("initialize")
            
        else:
            for process in processes:
                process.cq.put("rehash")
        # a process will only read a new command from the cotnrol queue when the previous 
        # command is done - no need to add any waiting on the client side -
        # but if there is some result to be read on the "queue" you passed
        # first, you could loop here waiting for the result of each task before sending a 
        # new command to the respective process.

    # this just needs to run when all tasks are done
    for process in processes: # wait until all processes finished the task before launching another iteration
        process.cq.put("finish")
        process.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    command()
```

Note that to simplify the code, I recreated a new "command queue" (cq), which is different for each process.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering so fast! I like your idea of a command queue to pass several tasks to a process. The only issue I have with your solution is that I really need for processes to wait for each other at the end of each iteration before launching the next one. I updated my toy example with a shared memory array which is aggregated at the end of each iteration by the main process. Let me know if you get the issue and if you happen to have a solution in mind.
Thanks again!

Comment: If you have signals some tasks have to reveive in order to start, the obviouus thing to do is to communicate the prior task are tone. You can use multiprocessing.pipe to have the "command" function comunicate back when a task is done, and that can be used to send an order to start another worker. Using a common queue for all workers so that each see the same message also can be done(for example to place a task for whichever worker is free). I think the main pattern you were not seeing is that you can use fixed worker processes. What you are asking now is a coding job.